# Есть последовательность вывести те, которые входят в нее только раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества

Ниже описана логика моего кода, к сожалению он работает некорректно. Спасибо за любую помощь.

```
a = input("enter numbers")
a = a.split(" ")     # Разделение ввода 
s = set(a)           # Создание множества которое имеет все элементы ввода
b=[i for i in s]     # Создание списка из множества(необязательно)
for i in a :         # Для всех элементов ввода
    if i in b:       # Если элемент есть в "в" удалить его
       a.remove(i)   # Получаем повторяющиеся элементы 
a = set(a)           # Помещаем их  в множество
m = s - a            # Отнимаем от всех элементов повторки 
print(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Какого именно результата ты хочешь добиться, и что именно не получается? Я вижу в этом коде отсутствие табуляции под условием, возможно именно это и есть проблема?

```
a = input("enter numbers")
a = a.split(" ") # Разделение ввода 
s = set(a)       # Создание множества которое имеет все элементы ввода
b=[i for i in s] # Создание списка из множества(необязательно)
for i in a :     # Для всех элементов ввода
    if i in b:       # Если элемент есть в "в" удалить его
        a.remove(i)  # Получаем повторяющиеся элементы 
a = set(a)       # Помещаем их  в множество
m = s - a        # Отнимаем от всех элементов повторки 
print(m)
```

Если я всё правильно понял, то мой вариант

```
x = '1233'
print([i for i in x if x.count(i) == 1])
```

Comment: не получается правильно получить множество повторок, почему-то результат не стабилен, в чем проблема понять не смог. Код который предложили вы полностью подходит. Спасибо

Comment: @OleksiyKoval, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Это тот самый случай когда лучше всё стереть и написать по новой. У списков есть метод `count`, ты можешь сделать `split`, и в цикле с помощью `list.count(i)` просто проверять больше 1, или меньше. Написал вот тут, можешь почитать https://pastebin.com/tGJxJmi2. Ещё советую почитать PEP8, поможет писать красивый и читаемый код. Удачи!